# IP Protocol left for development

Tags: ip, protocol-theory

I'm designing a custom application, which needs a custom IP packet.

In order to identify the traffic, I need an open protocol number, left for development.

In layer 2, I used the `0x88b5` : *"available for public use for prototype development"* ([source](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/ethertype/eth.txt))

Does such a protocol number exist for the IP layer ?

I searched [IANA Protocol Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml), but wasn't able to find one.

Comment: *PS : is it the right SE to post this ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the [IANA Protocol Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml). It depends on what you want to do. For instance, protocol 61 or 63 may fit. You just need to study to see which one is for you.

Comment: Could the 253 or 254 be used ? They are for  "Experimentation and testing". It won't impact the routing behavior, will it ?

Comment: Those are probably fine. Unless there is something like an ACL which blocks those protocols, a router normally doesn't care about the protocol of the packets it is switching.